# Add existing images from server to create gallery

Tags: media, files

I want to create gallery based on folder structure on the server. Basically just auto create a node for each folder and add all the images from server in that folder. I also don't want it auto create thumbnails. I found this tutorial https://www.drupal.org/node/1266646 but the problem is it only works on version 6 but I'm using version 7. So anyone have any alternative solutions? please note I'm not a programmer so I wouldn't know how to update the code on that tutorial site.

Comment: Find a module that do multi file upload, then upload the whole folder pics from single form.

Comment: but that's not what I want cause I want to add existing images from server

Comment: As you are not a developer I ma suggesting solutions that do the job for drupal interface, After uploading the files remove the old one if you are not using them to reduce duplicates, But surely if those files are in usage you will face duplication, The best solution needs some coding.